# Want to fix some columns

Tags: jqgrid

I want to fix some columns so that user cannot drag and drop these columns and cannot reorder these columns also.Is it doable how can i do it.

Comment: I have found {frozen:true} option but it fixes the columns even when we are traversing horizontally.I dont want to freeze these columns but  need that user should not be able to reorder these columns.

Answer (score 0):

There is code inside [grid.jqueryui.js](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/master/js/grid.jqueryui.js) that uses the [jQuery UI Sortable Interaction](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/) to enable drag-and-drop columns.

The following selector determines which columns can be dragged-and-dropped:

```
"items": '>th:not(:has(#jqgh_'+tid+'_cb'+',#jqgh_'+tid+'_rn'+',#jqgh_'+tid+'_subgrid),:hidden)',
```

So basically the selector will choose any column header that is not hidden and does not satisfy one of the following criteria:

- `#jqgh_'+tid+'_cb'` - A checkbox column (for multi-select)
- `#jqgh_'+tid+'_rn'` - A row number column (for primary key?)
- `#jqgh_'+tid+'_subgrid` - A subgrid column

To satisfy your request, jqGrid would have to be modified to populate the `items` selector with blacklisted columns. Maybe the blacklisted columns could be flagged using a new `colmodel` option. This is all do-able, but requires changes to jqGrid itself...